# What is this cylinder on the Martian surface at the Viking 2 landing site?

Tags: mars, viking

What is the cylinder on the Martian surface in this image taken by the Viking 2 lander?

[image: viking 2 image with cylinder]

It stands out in most images of the martian surface, including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_2#/media/File:Viking_Lander_2_Camera_1_NOON_HIGH_RESOLUTION_COLOR_MOSAIC.jpg

Comment: Test sample? Engine Bell? landing tank? Good question @foobarbecue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[It is a protective shroud for the surface sampler instrument, which was ejected after landing.](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/imgcat/html/ency_captions/vl2_22g144.html)

Comment: The shroud is listed in this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_on_Mars

Comment: So the first thing the lander did was throw trash on the surface of Mars???

Comment: @JonCuster, could be worse.  The first thing sent to the Moon was [a pair of fragmentation grenades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_2).

Comment: Link works better without the sandia header: https://xkcd.com/2125/